# Solve using the Laplace transform of the initial value problem

Tags: calculus, laplace-transform, inverse-laplace, primary-decomposition

The given equation and initial values are:
$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+25x=50e^{5t}$$
$$x(0)=0 \space, x^{'}(0)=0$$
Then taking the Laplace transform of the given:
$$\mathscr{L}\left[x^{''}+25x \right]=\mathscr{L}[50e^{5t}]$$
$$s^2X(s)-x^{'}(0)-x(0)+25X(s)=\frac{50}{s-5}$$
Solving for $X(s)$:
$$X(s)=\frac{50}{(s-5)(s^2+25)}$$
Then we have to decompose the above expression:
$$\frac{A}{s-5}+\frac{Bs+c}{s^2+25}$$
$$50=A(s^2+25)+(Bs+C)(s-5)$$
Substituting in for $s=5$:
$$50=50A \to A=1$$
Now we plug in our value for $A$ , then expand and factorizing yields:
$$50=s^2(1+B)+s(-5B+C)+(-5C+25)$$
Now to equate the coefficients:
$$(1):50=25-5C$$
$$(2):0=C-5B$$
$$(3):0=1+B$$ 
Solving equation $(1)$ for $C$ results with $C=-5$, then looking at equation $(3)$ we can deduce that $B=-1$

So now our Laplace transform looks like:
$$X(s)=\frac{1}{s-5}+\frac{-s-5}{s^2+25}$$

After splitting up the second term and taking the inverse Laplace transform the answer I got is:
$$e^{5t}-\cos(5t)-\sin(5t)$$

Comment: Your answer is correct

Comment: Looks good to me too Eric +1

Answer (score 1):

Your answer looks correct to me. Note that this IVP is simply:
$$\frac{d^2x}{du^2}+x=2e^{u}$$
$$x(0)=0,x'(0)=0$$
Where $u=5t$.
Apply Laplace's Transform:
$$X(s)(s^2+1)=\dfrac 2 {s-1}$$
$$X(s)=\dfrac 2 {(s^2+1)(s-1)}$$
$$X(s)=\dfrac  1 {s-1}-\dfrac {(s+1)} {s^2+1}$$
Take inverse Lapalce transform:
$$x(u)=e^u-\cos u -\sin u$$
$$\boxed {x(t)=e^{5t}-\cos (5t) -\sin (5t)}$$